# Is there any way to simplify the following meijerG function?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, approximation

I'm trying to approximate the following Meijer-G function as $x$ goes to zero.

$G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left( {_{0,0,1}^0\left| x \right.} \right) \xrightarrow{x \rightarrow 0} \;\; \simeq ???$

To this end, I think the first step should be simplifying it. However, I'm unable to do it. I tried with both Mathematica and MuPAD of Matlab but all failed.

Can anybody give me a hint how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you sent me in a comment seems to be $$f(x)=G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0,0,1
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Using a CAS, a series expansion gives
$$f(x)=-2 \gamma-\log (x) +x \left(\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(x)+(2 \gamma -1) \log (x)+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}+2 \gamma ^2-2 \gamma +1\right)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ Using $x=10^{-k}$ and computing
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 1 & 1.703729585 & 1.757868806 \\
 2 & 3.586579192 & 3.587682919 \\
 3 & 5.779898277 & 5.779917509 \\
 4 & 8.060388203 & 8.060388503 \\
 5 & 10.35917711 & 10.35917711 \\
 6 & 12.66117633 & 12.66117633 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The series expansion is more than OK for me.

Do you have any idea how to obtain the series analytically?

Comment: Did you try **Series[f[x],{x,0,1}]** with Mathematica ? It should work.